# menuSubItem in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to add submenu in sidebar of shinydashbaord but it does not show,
Where is my problem:

```
  shinyUI( 
  dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
    dashboardHeader(title = "Decison Support System"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Setting", tabName = "setting", icon = icon("cog")),
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Charts", tabName = "charts", icon = icon("bar-chart"),
            menuSubItem("subcharts", tabName = "subcharts",icon = icon("cog")
      )),
      menuItem("Raw Data", tabName = "rawdata", icon = icon("table")))
      ),
    dashboardBody(
  )

))
```

Comment: on my r all works fine

Comment: But in mine does not work, is it possible that It is not in ui.r and it is in admin.r

Comment: It works for me When I created a single page for each admin and user. Thank you so much.